# NSURLConnection times out on addresses on the same subnet

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, subnet

I am using NSURLConnection on an iPhone 4s, iOS5.1.1, and having problems calling out to a php script on a machine which is on the same subnet, say: http://myMac.local/PHPscript.php
The same URL works works fine on that iPhone using Safari and my code also works great -as long as the machine is somewhere on the internet-.
On a local machine it runs in some kind of time out and just plain returns nothing.
When testing with the Simulator either all 3 (name, IP, external name) work or they don't. no idea yet what causes thing to start working ...
The error reported is: NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., NSUnderlyingError=0x24e6c0. Couldn't find that number :-(

Any pointers as to where I could continue looking (Googling for NSURLConnection & time out is driving me nuts by now :-< )

Comment: Try using your IP (192.168.x.x) instead of the myMac.local. It could be the name lookup that is failing

Comment: Hi James, tnx for the feedback. Just go back to this problem and it continues to confuse me. Here's what I got today:

Comment: tnx for the feedback. I am switching to using the IP for the servers on testing. Updated my question with testing results from today. Hope this helps somebody ... (btw. you can tell this is my first posting here, right :-> )

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me as well. Then I reported to my IT guy and he said that that we don't forward request to Internet service provider which points to their IP. Thus I make a solution for it as

```
#if DEBUG
#define BASE_URL 192.168.x.x
#else
#define IP_ADDRESS www.mysite.com
#endif
```

Debug build for simulator and Release build for iPhone.